# Change background-image size in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been attempting to put a repeating background image on a website, with the basic CSS

```
background-image: url('url_here');
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

however, id like to be able to change the size of the image im using on refresh, using javascript. CSS has the function

```
background-size: 300px;
```

but unfortunately the COM style object doesnt - see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp#background) for what it can do for backgrounds. This leaves me with one option: using an HTML image that repeats itself, that i can then edit with the COM style object.

So, boiled down, my question is: is there a way to repeat an HTML image that is NOT a background image? Any help is greatly appreciatted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you CAN affect the background size in javascript like so:

```
document.getElementById("el_id").style.backgroundSize = "100px 100px";
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lph2W/.  The CSS sets the background image size to 200px X 200px, then the JS updates it to 100px X 100px.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me and I hope this helps some one else.

```
var el = document.getElementById("notification");
el.style.background = 'url(images/Noti.png) no-repeat center center';
el.style.backgroundSize="100% 100%";
```

If you found this useful please don't forget to vote UP :)

Comment: Can you add more details as to why this helps the original question?  I'm not clear it actually answers it.

Comment: To answer question better, you can just repeat the quote eg. <img src and keep repeating it manually

Answer (score 1):

It appears that using:

```
style.backgroundSize = 300px;
```

in the place of:

```
style.background-size = 300px;
```

solves this issue, but I wanted to point out a shorthand version as well:

```
style.background = "url('url_here') repeat fixed /300px";
```

just remember to keep the background size on the end, as if its added in the middle it seems to break.